# Generate meta data from EntityFramework with partial class

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4

I have a class like

using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
    }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public int BuyerID { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual Buyer Buyer { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

which is provide by EntityFramework. 
 I have got meta data of the entityframework properly. But I want to add new two Columns as follows

public partial class Order
    {
        public string BuyerName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
"After adding new columns when I fetch metadata but system does not return "BuyerName" and UserName" in metadata. what should  Do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "BuyerName" and UserName" are two new columns added to "Order" table.
In this case you need to **update the Database Model (*.edmx file) (Update Model From DataBase)** to get the mapping information for these new columns.

If you want  to add only these properties to the Order class without any real columns in the database, then no need of update the Edmx file.